# Warm-up scripts for MOSS/WSS

Tags: 2007, wss, warm-up

I'm looking for a comprehensive guide to creating and using warm-up scripts for a SharePoint installation (WSS/MOSS).

How do i create one? What should be in it? What not? How does it get run after every app-pool recycle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Andrew Connell has written one for [2007](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/archive/2008/04/15/More-help-on-creating-custom-timer-jobs-and-a-useful.aspx) and for [2010](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/archive/2010/03/27/introducing-the-sharepoint-site-collection-keep-alive-job.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20AndrewConnell%20%28Andrew%20Connell%20%5BMVP%20SharePoint%5D%29), they are pretty well received.

Answer (score 1):

- This [MSDN blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20121014113133/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/joelo/archive/2006/08/13/697044.aspx) has links to warmup script for SharePoint.
- This [Andrew Connell](https://web.archive.org/web/20220522151310/https://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/SharePoint-developer-tips-and-tricks/) post has some guidance as well.
- My favourite is [this one](https://nearbaseline.com/2010/02/powershell-warmup-script-2/) that uses Powershell